# How to repeat string and take parts of it in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I need to write a Haskell program that takes an integer and a list and repeats the characters of the list up to n digits:

```
Int -> [a] -> [a]
```

e.g. `3 "pink"` would give `"pin"`
`6 "blue"` would give `"bluebl"`

I'm new to the Haskell so cannot form the logic or don't know if there's any function to do it.

Comment: What is your question? Keep in mind that "How do I write code to do this?" isn't considered an on-topic question here. Show us what you thought might work, and explain what went wrong when you tried that.

Answer (score 8):

One simple implementation would be to use [`cycle`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:cycle) and [`take`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:take):

```
takeRepeated :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
takeRepeated n = take n . cycle
```